# GoogleMaps JS API v3 cluster multiple data types seperately

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps, markerclusterer, azure-maps

I want to use MarkerClusterer with multiple markers of different type and cluster them separately. For example, cluster markers of type X only with other markers of type X, and markers of type y, with other markers of type y.

There are different types of markers in my map (not all the markers represent the same type of element)

I need it to cluster all the markers in the map if the zoom is lower or equal than 15 (easy part).

What I can't achieve is clustering the markers by the type of the marker when zoom is higher than 15.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you provide more clarity on what your trying to achieve. Do you want different icons for the clusters based on the data they represent. For example if a cluster has 10 locations and majority of them are of type X, then show a X cluster icon?

Comment: Yes. For example if in a location there are 10 markers, 5 with one type and 5 with other type, I want to appear one cluster icon for each type. (a cluster for the 5 with one type and another cluster for the 5 with the other type).

Comment: Ok, that is a bit different. In your case you are clustering each type of data separately essentially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is possible with Google Maps, you likely will need to separate your markers ahead of time and pass each group of markers into a separate MarkerCluster.

You may also want to take a look at Azure Maps. It has a lot more functionality when it comes to clustering (also a lot cheaper than Google Maps). In Azure Maps you would group your markers of the same type into different data sources and enable clustering on the data sources. Here are some resources:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/clustering-point-data-web-sdk

https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/index.html?search=cluster

Comment: I'll give a try to Azure then.

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway. I achieved what I wanted doing what you said =)

Comment: One other thought. If you have two or more layers that are clustered separately, you will end up with clusters overlapping. Another idea is to use a single layer and have the clusters show the amount of each type in it, for example: https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/index.html?sample=Clustered%20Pie%20Chart%20HTML%20Markers